# Preventing weird wrist pain

Tags: pain, wrist

I have a recurring issue where, for a week or two at a time randomly with anywhere from weeks to months in between, one wrist will exhibit excruciating pain when attempting to bend it up or down past a certain angle. That angle varies as it get worse and better.

For example, normally I am able to do a push-up with my hand in the normal position (as though you were gesturing "STOP" to the ground), but when this pain comes, I cannot do this and instead must use a fist. Ibuprofen taken for anti-inflammatory purposes has no effect

I have never experienced tingling/numbness with respect to this. I saw a doctor about it who also did tests and believes it is not Carpal Tunnel Syndrome. They ran X-Rays but did not see anything.

I know this is a long-shot, but **are there any exercises I can do to strengthen my wrist in such a way to prevent this from occurring?**

Comment: Darn. It was migrated. That means I won't get a tumbleweed badge at health.SE.......... But hopefully I'll get an answer!

Answer (score 2):

It depends which part of the wrist you want to reinforce.

I suggest to strenghten your hand muscles and your forearm muscle. Any grip based exercise will be good. 
Armwrestlers use [these type of tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captains_of_Crush_Grippers) to strenghten their grip power and aswell their wrist and forearm muscles.

Also try to work on your **range of motion**. Remember that having a healty fascia tissue is key to avoid injuries.

[Common stretching exercises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oylx0Up7nG8) for forearms are not so complicated and you can find them anywhere.